How to use duplicate rows of input forms for dash app?
I am new to Dash and working on a personal finance app, which will include spending tracking. I'd ideally like to have multiple rows of input forms so the user can add multiple transactions, or split out one receipt if they'd like. Does each input need to have a distinct id, or is there an easier way to go about this? An image and code is below.

from dash import Dash, dcc, html, dash_table, Input, Output, State, callback, callback_context
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

app = Dash(
    __name__,
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.FONT_AWESOME],
)

dropdown_values = ["Groceries", "Car Insurance", "Eating Out"]

amount_spent = dbc.Input(id="amount_spent",
                                type="number", value=0)

tax_rate = dbc.InputGroup([dbc.InputGroupText("Tax Rate"),dbc.Input(id="tax_rate",
                                type="number")], className="mb-3")

total = dbc.InputGroup([dbc.InputGroupText("Total"),dbc.Input(id="total",
                                type="number", value=0)], className="mb-3")

input_boxes = [amount_spent, tax_rate, total]

dummy_tab = html.H2("Header for dummy tab")

expense_tab = dbc.Container([dbc.Row([dbc.Col(html.H4("Category"), width=12, lg=2), dbc.Col(html.H4("Amount Spent"), width=12, lg=3), dbc.Col(html.H4("Tax Rate"), width=12, lg=3), dbc.Col(html.H4("Total"), width=12, lg=3)]),
                                    dbc.Row(
                                        [dbc.Col(
                                            dcc.Dropdown(id="category-dropdown", multi=False, options=[{"label": x, "value":x} for x in ["Eating Out", "Groceries", "Entertainment"]]), lg=2),
                                                         dbc.Col(amount_spent, lg=3), dbc.Col(tax_rate, lg=3), dbc.Col(total, lg=3),
                                         dbc.Col(html.Button("+", id="add-row", n_clicks=0), lg=1)
                                            
                                         ]
                                        ),

                                                         dbc.Row([html.Button("Submit", id="submit-button", n_clicks=0, disabled=True), html.Button("+", id="add-row-button", n_clicks=0),
                                      html.Div(id="spending-output")])])



@app.callback(
    Output('total', 'value'),
    [Input('amount_spent', 'value'), Input('tax_rate', 'value')], prevent_initial_call=True)

def update_total(spent_value, tax_value):
    total_amount = round(spent_value*(1+(tax_value/100)),2)
    return total_amount


@app.callback(
    Output('submit-button', 'disabled'),
    Input('total', 'value'), prevent_initial_call=True)

def enable_submit(total):
    if total>0:
        return False
    elif total<=0:
        return True

@callback(
    Output('spending-output', 'children'),
    Input('submit-button', 'n_clicks'),
    State('category-dropdown', 'value'), State('total', 'value'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)

def update_spending(n_clicks, category, total):
    print('I am here')
    data = {'Category':[category], 'Amount':[total]}
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    df.to_excel("dummy_spending_data.xlsx")


tabs = dbc.Tabs([dbc.Tab(dummy_tab, label="Dummy"), dbc.Tab(expense_tab, label="Expenses")])
app.layout = dbc.Row(dbc.Col(tabs))
                                        






if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)



Does each input need to have a distinct id ?
Yes, there is a feature designed for this kind of stuff : Pattern-Matching Callbacks. It allows dynamically created components of a specific (custom) "type" to be used as a single input (or state or output) in callbacks. This can be done using composite ids, ie. instead of having a component with id='total', you would have id={'type': 'total', index: 0} initially in the layout, and then in callbacks you would use one of the index selectors MATCH, ALL, or ALLSMALLER.

Is there an easier way to go about this ?
Yes absolutely (well, in my opinion), you could use an editable DataTable instead.


